# function pointer with generic argument type

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

for knowledge sake, I would like to know if something like this is possible:

2 function:

```
static int func1(int *a, int b){
...
}

static int func2(double *a, int b){
...
}
```

I would like to declare a function pointer and point it to one of these function. However the arguments of these functions are of different type. So I tried:

```
static int (*func_ptr)(void *arg1, int arg2);
static void *Argument1;
static int Argument2=5;
int main(){
 double arg1_d;;
 int arg1_i;
 ...
 if(want_func2){
  Argument1=(double *) &arg1_d;
  func_ptr=func2;
  run(func_ptr);
 }
 else{
  Argument1=(int *) &arg1_i;
  func_ptr=func1;
  run(func_ptr);
 }
 return 0;
}

static int run(int *(function)(void *,int )){
function(Argument1,Argument2);
}
```

However, when compiling I get the warning:

```
warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
```

when

```
func_ptr=func2;
func_ptr=func1;
```

Is there anyway to create a function pointer with a generic type argument?

Comment: Maybe `run(int *(function)())`?

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. But, in order to achieve what you want, your functions should have a void* parameter and cast it internally to int or double.

Answer (score -1):

No.  You need the `if`...`else` to use such a thing correctly anyway, so just store separate function pointers and use the correct pointer in each piece of code.

Comment: There are valid cases where this is wanted... think the first parameter as an "self" parameter for example.